# tool to calculate patterns from different set assuming every set uses the same rules

Tags: correlation

I am looking for a tool that takes in sets, for example:

$200 = 300$

$600 = 700$

$44400 = 44500$

And i want the program to tell me the rules of the set, for example
'add $100$'

I need this to test complicated results to find out how it was calculated.

There are tools to calculate the continuation of sets out there. But i have not found one that fits my needs.

Comment: Do you mean $G_f = \{ (200,300), (600,700), (44400, 44500) \} \subseteq A \times B $ for some $f : A \to B$?

Comment: yes :) i have many real sets i need to find the pattern to.

Answer (score 1):

The book [A=B](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) is about checking identities in general (how do we verify that $A$ is indeed equal to $B$?) and recognizing certain integer sequences (which can be viewed as functions with the natural numbers as domain).

On interesting definition is the one about "closed form":

> Definition 8.1.1: A function $f(n)$ is said to be of closed form if it
>   is equal to a linear combination of a fixed number, $r$, say, of
>   hypergeometric terms. The number $r$ must be an absolute constant,
>   i.e., it must be independent of all variables and parameters of the
>   problem.

This is taylored for their pet pet problem, hypergeometric series, but the interesting bit seems to be the finiteness of the term, not unlike the Wikipedia definition [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

You seem to expect something along this line, entering some set of pairs $P_i = (x_i, y_i)$ and as answer expecting some function $f$ given by a finite sized expression, which fulfills $(x_i, f(x_i))$ for all the indices $i$.

The naive solution is to provide a list of expected operations and basic functions of which the solution candidate functions can be built from.
Then one generates all possible expressions up to a certain size, and checks if the candidate expression matches the given set of data points $P_i$.

In practice there might be a lot of possible expressions to check and the task fails due to this combinatorial explosion.

The A=B book seems to show a problem, where the authors managed to get that sheer size under control by clever reasoning.